# How to inject property to the root element from HOC in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to add className to the root of component using HOC.

```
const Component = () => <div>...</div>;
const ComponentWithHello = withHello(Component);
```

`ComponentWithHello` should render for example `<div className="hello">...</div>`.
I think I could do something like this using [render highjacking](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e), but there is typecheck error:

```
function withHello<T>(WrappedComponent: React.Component<T>) {
  return class Enhancer extends WrappedComponent {} //Error here
}
```

`Type 'Component<T, {}, any>' is not a constructor function type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to extend a *value* of type `React.Component<T>` (i.e. what you'd get if you called `new Component`), not the class itself.

`WrappedComponent` should be of type `React.ComponentType` instead.

Comment: `React.ComponentClass` this also can be used.

`function withHello<T>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<T>) {
    return class Enhancer extends WrappedComponent {} 
  }`

Comment: @Harish - True, but `ComponentClass` will only accept class components, whereas `ComponentType` will accept both class components and functional components. Therefore I'd recommend using the latter.